# Every Maximal ideal contains either a or b

Tags: ring-theory

Let R be a commutative ring and if ab belongs to Jacobson radical of R then every maximal ideal of R contains either a or b. How to prove this?
Suppose not then let M be a maximal ideal that doesn't contain either a or b.
But ab belongs M
Then i couldn't arrive at a contradiction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** note that

$$
J(R) = \bigcap_{\mathfrak m  \text{ maximal}} \mathfrak m
$$

and that maxmimal ideals are prime.

> Pick an element $ab \in J(R)$. Then $ab$ lies in each maximal $\mathfrak m$, which in particular is prime. Hence by primality $ab \in \mathfrak m$ implies either $a \in \mathfrak m$ or $b \in \mathfrak m$.

Comment: Ok i get it since every maximal ideal is a prime ideal, thank you